# How to add padding between the TreeView control's contents and its edges

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add padding between the TreeView control's contents and its edge in windows form application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a "margin" ([padding is inside, margin is outside](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229627.aspx)).

[image: Padding and margin Visual]

[TreeView.Margin property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx):

> Gets or sets the space between controls.

However, if your `TreeView` is docked it will not respect this setting:

> Setting the Margin property on a docked control has no effect on the distance of the control from the the edges of its container.

So you would have to place your `TreeView` in a `Panel`, dock the `Panel` and put the margin on the `TreeView`.

Comment: The op has asked for a winform treeview and I dont think so there is a property like padding in winforms Treeview.

Comment: @Apocalyp5e: that is correct. The OP was asking about Margins. The picture is a stock image from MSDN that happened to include padding.

Comment: you are right in explaining the difference between padding margin and that is applicable to many winforms controls, but I have yet to find padding property in winforms Treeview. The best you can do with winforms treeview is to set its height, or you need to paint it yourself using DrawMode as owner draw all.

Comment: @Apocalyp5e: The OP was looking for **margin** but thought it was called *padding*. I'm not sure what you're trying to say.